# How to remove template markup if data is missing in Handlebars?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

How would one remove all the template markup from a HTML snippet if the data wasn't present.

```
var $target = $(target);
var dataString = // json from feed ! Sometimes fails

if( typeof dataString !== "undefined") {
    var data = $.parseJSON(dataString);
    var template = Handlebars.compile($target.html());
    var html = template(integrationData);
    $target.html(html);
} else {
    // What goes here?
    // I am making up "stripTags"
    Handlebars.stripTags($target.html());
}
```

Basically I want to automatically strip out all the `{{` and `}}` as a failsafe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlebars will ignore any {{whatever}} if the object does not exist and they will be removed from the markup.

If your feed fails default to an empty object:

```
var $target = $(target);
var dataString = // json from feed ! Sometimes fails
var data = {};

if( typeof dataString !== "undefined") {
    data = $.parseJSON(dataString);
}

var template = Handlebars.compile($target.html());
var html = template(data);
$target.html(html);
```

Hope that helps?